# "MYSCHEMA.sessions" is an undefined name

Tags: node.js, session, db2, session-storage, db2-connect

When I try to connect to SESSIONS table which I created in the appropriate schema, I get this error:

> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N "MYSCHEMA.sessions" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704

I pass the DSN to the session like this:

```
var session = require("express-session")
  , Db2Store = require('connect-db2')(session);
var options = {
  dsn: 'DATABASE=MyDB;HOSTNAME=IpAddr;PORT=myPort;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db2_admin;PWD=db2_pwd;CurrentSchema=MYSCHEMA;'
}
var sessionStore = new Db2Store(options);
app.use(session({
  store: sessionStore,
  secret: "AAAAA:ZZZZZ:EEEEE"
}));
```

Did I miss something here ?

Comment: According to the error message, you are trying to select from `"sessions"`, not `"SESSIONS"`.  You may want to include the _exact_ select statement that causes the error.

Comment: I'm using a node module "connect-db2" which does that for me. I'm not typing no query to the sessions table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to DB2 auto-capitalize issue: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0203adamache/0203adamache.html#N1011C, I had to put table name, columns and As clause between quotes when creating sessions table and also inside the module in connect-db2/lib/connect-db2.js file